# Why is there a comma after the word “recipient”?

Tags: commas, conjunctions

Writing sample below (first sentence, not second)

> The statement is also in the interest of the **recipient**, as a person seeking an attorney would likely want to know if an attorney only wants easy cases.

I ask this question because if I were to replace the word **as** with the word **since**  or ***because*** in the writing sample above, the comma would not be necessary.

Comment: I disagree. Whichever word you use, the sentence reads better to me if the explanation is preceded by a comma.

Comment: The inclusion of the comma, in this sort of situation largely a style choice where it is not needed to disambiguate, is here better on three counts. (1) As Kate says, the comma aids in general construal, the forced pause helping by nicely partitioning first statement and reason. (2) Such a lengthy sentence is unwieldy whatever the subsections. If read out, the comma helps the reader not to lose their breath. (3) The string _the recipient as a person_ can elsewhere be cohesive; the comma forestalls the garden path construal.

Comment: I agree with Kate and (as usual) Edwin above. Still the most constructive advise I have heard about the comma is that we use them too often.